не получается создать виртуальную среду venv в django
когда пишу команду python -m venv venv, он мне отвечает "Python" на следующей строчке и ничего не происходит. пробывал переустановить пайтон , не помогло

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Выводит Python в командной строке вместо запуска интерпретатора python
